# Как сформировать SQL запрос из двух таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

Ребята, помогите максимально лаконично сформировать SQL запрос к БД для вывода информации.

Есть 2 таблицы, **partners** и **cupons**

Таблица **partners** содержит имена партнеров в поле name. Структура таблицы такова: **id; name;**

Таблица **cupons** содержит информацию о купонах, проданных по каждому из партнеров. Структура таблицы такова: **id; idpartner; summa; date;**

Мне необходимо вывести на экран таблицу такого вида:

**Имя партнера; количество купонов, общая сумма**

Таблица должна быть сгруппирована по имени партнера.

Резюмируя, мне необходимо вывести 1 раз имя партнера и посчитать для него количество проданных купонов и общую сумму для него, за определенный период date.

**Важно отметить**, что если для партнера не было за период date продано купонов, то его выводить **не нужно**

Как сформировать циклы и запросы для вывода такой таблицы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Берешь и выводишь:

```
$sql = "SELECT `p`.`name`, COUNT(1) as `cnt`, SUM(`c`.`summa`) as `summ`
FROM `partners` `p`
INNER JOIN `cupons` `c` ON `p`.`id` = `c`.`idpartner`
WHERE `c`.`date` BETWEEN ? AND ?;";
```

Рекомендую [ознакомиться](https://www.google.ru/search?q=mysql+joins&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ_Zi9uPfWAhUiMZoKHQ30AFQQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=965). Они там все одинаковые, можете выбрать на любой цвет.

Далее исполняем запрос и выводим в цикле:

```
$pdo = new PDO(/*данные для коннекта*/);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$date1,$date2]);
while ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    print $row['name'] . "\t";
    print $row['cnt'] . "\t";
    print $row['summ'] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это запрос, а можете дополнить ответ циклом? что бы я увидел как вывести именно информацию из массива, та как в массиве по сути должна храниться информация из двух таблиц. И можете подправить, что бы с таблицы партнера выводилось не только имя а к пример все, т.е *

Comment: и по поводу date также если можно внести корректировку в ваш ответ, так как я говорил если за период date у партнера не было продано купонов его ненужно выводить

Comment: @WhoIsDT, не знаю, что у Вас там - pdo или mysqli, написал для pdo, потому что я не знаю mysqli. Но для него примерно также делается.